# Gradle project sync fails with ParseError

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

Gradle keeps failing to sync the project.

I get the following error message:

[image]

For best of my understating, the interpreter has an issue with parsing the module's `build.gradle` file.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```json
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.b.b3"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        maxSdkVersion 28
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.2'
}

ext {
    supportLibrary = "27.0.2"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}"
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you check the following setting in your build.gradle file?

```
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:xxxxx'
  }
```

I used to have the same problem as you. I don't know why. But I adjusted the above version information and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you. There is definitely an issue with Gradle version. The version was "3.3.0-alpha11". I changed it to "3.3.0-alpha12" and still had the same issue. Then I changed it to "3.2.0" and now I'm able to sync the project. What could be wrong with "3.3.0-alpha11/12" ?